# How to make a button go to a link from an array in React?

Tags: reactjs, button, hyperlink

I want to have a button to go to Codepen. The thing is, when I try doing:

`<button onClick="https://codepen.io">CodePen</button>`

And click on the button, it doesn't do anything. By anything, I mean it doesn't go to the URL, or open a  new tab to go to the site.

I also don't want to use React Router, because I tried to do this:

```
<Router>
    <Link to="https://codepen.io"/>
</Router>
```

And it gives me this error:

[image: Error]

My full code is [here.](https://pastecode.io/s/XhXbqb59bD) Also I do have imports, I just replaced them with // Imports because there's way to many.

Comment: You need to pass a function: `<button onClick={() => window.location.href = 'https://codepen.io'}>CodePen</button>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<button onClick={() => window.location.href = 'https://codepen.io'}>CodePen</button>
```

Comment: I copied and pasted that code, and it still doesn't do anything. I tried it on Brave and Edge, and I still have that problem.

Comment: are you using react?

Comment: Yes, I'm using React. I've also tried using a link, but I still can't do it.

Comment: i thought you are just trying it in the pure html, i just updated answer.

Comment: This works, but what if I want to make it like: `<button onClick={() => window.location.href = {website.codepen}>CodePen</button>`? I tried doing it but I can't. It redirects me to `http://localhost:3000/undefined`.

Comment: remove curly brace for the website.codepen. window.location.href = website.codepen

Comment: It still gives `http://localhost:3000/undefined`. Also here's some example code of what I mean: https://pastecode.io/s/9w1un4g1ib

Comment: `website` is the array of the object, so maybe you need to use website[0].codepen

Comment: That works...except this is my full code: pastecode.io/s/XhXbqb59bD so actually I can't do website[0].link because I have a template div card. Is it possible so it would be able to each have their own links for their own card? I can make 3 cards, but if there's another way, that'll be great.

Comment: looping variable inside map is the same - `website`, you may need to rename it like `website.map((w, index)`, and then use `onClick={() => window.location.href = w.link}`

Comment: Thank you William! I copied Hao's code and then followed your suggestion of the array and it worked!